# Saving data within a service in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm working with a service to pull data from an api as a user types into a textbox.  Everything works great until the user clicks on the detail page of an item.  The app routes to the item, then upon pressing the back button within the app, the user's input is not saved and the input and movie list component are empty.

**Problem: I'm looking for the Angular 2 way of saving this input so that when a user returns to the movie list, the data is there for their previous search query**

*The user inputs their movie title here, where an observable is returned from the movie service after a user stops typing.*

**search-textbox.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-textbox',
  templateUrl: './search-textbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-textbox.component.scss'],
  providers: [MovieService]
})
export class SearchTextboxComponent implements OnInit {

  private movies;
  private title = new FormControl();

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) {
    this.title.valueChanges
             .debounceTime(400)
             .distinctUntilChanged()
             .flatMap(title => this.movieService.getMovies(title))
             .subscribe(movies => this.movies = movies);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**search-textbox.component.html**

```
<div class="row searchbox">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" [formControl]="title" placeholder="Enter Title" autofocus/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" [class.loading]="!movies && title.value ">
  <app-movie-list [movies]="movies"></app-movie-list>
</div>
```

*The movie list component has access to the movies returned from the api call via the input decorator.*

**movie-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.scss'],
  providers: [MovieService]
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() movies: Object[];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private movieService: MovieService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  gotoDetail(selectedMovieID): void {
    this.router.navigate(['./detail', selectedMovieID])
  }
}
```

**movie-list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies">
  <div *ngIf="movie.Poster != 'N/A'"
       class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="card">
       <img class="card-img-top" [src]="movie.Poster" alt="Card image cap">
       <div class="card-block">
         <h4 class="card-title">{{movie.Title}}</h4>
         <p class="card-text">{{movie.Year}}</p>
         <button (click)="gotoDetail(movie.imdbID)" class="btn btn-success">Details</button>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*When the user is rerouted back via this.location.back(), the search input is empty*

**movie-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieService } from '../movie.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-detail',
  templateUrl: './movie-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-detail.component.scss'],
  providers: [MovieService]
})

export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  private movie: Object;

  constructor(
    private movieService: MovieService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.movieService.getMovieDetails(params['id']))
        .subscribe((movie: Object) => this.movie = movie)
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

**movie-detail.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="movie">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img [src]="movie.Poster" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 movie-details">
      <h1>{{movie.Title}}: {{movie.Year}}</h1>
      <div *ngIf="movie.tomatoMeter != 'N/A'">
        <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-success" [class.progress-danger]="movie.tomatoMeter < 50" value="{{movie.tomatoMeter}}" max="100"></progress>
        <h1>{{movie.tomatoMeter}}%</h1>
        <div class="consensus">
          <p>{{movie.tomatoConsensus}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-info">Go Back</button>
</div>
```

**movie.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  private moviesUrl = 'http://omdbapi.com?s=';
  private movieDetailsUrl = 'http://omdbapi.com?i=';

  getMovies(searchInput: string) : Observable<Object[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.moviesUrl + searchInput)
                    .map((res:Response) => res.json().Search)
                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'error'));
  }

  getMovieDetails(movieID: string) : Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(this.movieDetailsUrl + movieID + '&tomatoes=true') // add rotten tomatoes param
                    .map((r: Response) => r.json())
                    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'error'));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On route loading the parameters don't retain.

You need to store them temporary in Session Storage/Location Storage.

1. On CanDeActivate() of List Page route, Store them in Location/Session Storage
2. On ngOnInit() method in SearchTextboxComponent, read from storage & bind it in to the template.